# Reference behaviour

Tags: java, reference

I have two instances for the same object, I made the main object null, but references still exist.
It will be nice, if someone can explain to me, what is happening? Maybe there are some techniques, which allow to make all reference null after making the main object null, instead of manually going through all instances and making them null.

```java
public class Node <Item> {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }

    public class JavaApplication1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Node<Integer> node = new Node<>();
           Node<Integer> node2 = new Node<>();
           Node<Integer> node3 = new Node<>();
           node.item = 1;

           node2 = node;
           node3 = node;
           node = null;

           //reference still exists in node2/node3 instances
           System.out.print(node2.item); // show 1
           System.out.print(node3.item); // show 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: "I have two instances for the same object". No, you have two references to the same object/instance.

Answer (score 2):

The `Node` object (when you do `new Node<>()`) is created in the Heap. Heap is a chunk of memory were all Objects reside. it is managed for you by the java run time (JRE). the object contains the instance variables, `item` and `next`, who happen to be two references to other objects that also reside in the heap.

references are pointers to addresses in the heap. `item`, `next` inside Node are references to different objects. `node`, `node2` and `node3` are references to the same object. an object will remain in the heap **as long as at least one** reference points to it. removal of objects from the heap is done automatically by the JRE. this is what is called garbage collection.

there is no automatic technique to get a list of references to an object. you have to manually maintain such a list.

Answer (score 0):

You create 3 instances of class `Node`. Let's call them N1, N2, and N3 for this.

Your code:

```
Node<Integer> node = new Node<>();  // node refers to N1
Node<Integer> node2 = new Node<>(); // node2 refers to N2
Node<Integer> node3 = new Node<>(); // node3 refers to N3
node.item = 1; // node refers to N1, so N1.item is now 1

node2 = node; // node2 now refers to N1
              // since no reference exists to N2, it will be deleted by the JVM
node3 = node; // node2 now refers to N1
              // since no reference exists to N3, it will be deleted by the JVM
node = null;  // node is now null

//reference still exists in node2/node3 instances
System.out.print(node2.item); // show 1, because node2 is referring to N1, and N1.item is 1
System.out.print(node3.item); // show 1, because node3 is referring to N1, and N1.item is 1
```

Comment: I think you should clarify what happens exactly with N1, as his logic (based on C I guess?) is that "N1 is null so why N1.item is 1?"

Something in the lines of "java does not have real references, by pointer1 = pointer2 you're not making the same you'd do in C" etc.

Comment: @Ssr1369 Seems you didn't understand my answer at all. `N1` is my nametag for an object instance. It represents the object itself (basically the allocate memory of the object), and cannot be `null`, and it has nothing whatsoever to do with the `node` *variable*, which can be `null`. Also, OP never said "N1 is null".

Comment: I understand it, the guy who made the question doesn't, because you're not clarifying the concept behind you saying "it represents the object and cannot be null, whereas the node variable can be null".